# How to convert time to epoch

Tags: php, mysql, date, time, epoch

How can I convert the following code below to epoch time?

```
starts = '" . date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($_POST['starts'])) . "',
```

I have been racking my brain for the last two days and I just cannot figure it out.

I am getting the date and time from datetimepicker and I need to convert the time from unix timestamp to epoch to store in the database. Thanks in advance for help.

***I'm using this command to write to MYSQL database***

Answer (score 1):

```
strtotime($starts);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Refer the php documentation for more details.

Note : UNIX Epoch is always in UTC.
So always set the default timezone using the **date_default_timezone_set();** function to get the desired output.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however I have been on that page numerous times over the past two days and cannot figure it out.

Comment: No, I am still at a huge loss. I am trying to use the command above to insert into mysql table and I just cannot for the life of me figure out how. All I keep finding is how to convert epoch to unix time stamp and I need the opposite.

Comment: Use the function I mentioned in the answer. And check your question. There's no MySql statement.

Comment: Well maybe that is my problem. I trying to get the date/time from a contact form and insert the date into the database from the form. I am using [DateTimePicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker) as the way to select date/time.